# Wrong spotlight icon in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone

I updated all the icons in the appIcon file in image.xcassets. But still spotlight shows the wrong app icon.

Is there anyway that I can specify which icon to use for spotlight? Or is this just a bug?

Comment: Try deleting the app from the phone, then in Xcode choose Product > (alt) Clean Build Folder.

Comment: @SomeGuy didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Re-booting the iPad seemed to clear out Spotlight's cached icon for me